# CM 11 Link volumes when toggling through (Silent, Vibrate, Noise)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-2, cyanogenmod

I have a question about CM 11 volumes.  I have a Sprint Galaxy Note II, running cm-11-20140226-NIGHTLY, and this is referring to the volume toggle that you can add when you pull down the right side of the notification bar (quick access tiles).

Basically, for the sound tile, is there a way to force all three of the phone volumes (ringer, media, and alarm) to go to zero when I am in silent or vibrate mode (well, the ringer volume would be set to vibrate for vibrate mode, but you get the point)?

Answer (score 1):

Go under Settings - Sound
Volumes -> check Silent mode affects notifications. Click OK
Under Notifications, check Vibrate on notification - In vibrate mode, all notifications will vibrate regardless of individual app settings.

Hope that helps.